# Removing IIS Role from Remote Desktop Services Installation

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I installed RDS on Windows Server 2012 R2 using the Remote Desktop Services Installation wizard, selecting the Quick-start, session based deployment options which seems to have installed the following roles:

- Remote Desktop Services (Connection Broker, Web Access & Session Host)
- IIS Web Server

I don't plan on using Web Access, however, and would like to know if I still need the IIS role installed if I uninstall the Web Access role.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the Connection Broker and Session Host roles don't depend on the Web Server role.

You can safely proceed to uninstall a role through Server Manager without knowing what roles depend on it, since Server Manager will warn you of any dependencies before going through with the uninstall.

Also, you can run the following command in Powershell to see what dependencies a role has before installing it.

```
Import-module ServerManager
Add-WindowsFeature name -whatIf
```

To find the name of the "feature" in question enter:

```
Get-WindowsFeature
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771197.aspx